# How to get a Connection from a Reactive app

Tags: spring-boot, database-connection, reactive-programming

In a non-reactive app, you can simply get the connection from the `DataSource`.

In Reactive, I found `ConnectionFactory`, but it returns an `org.reactivestreams.Publisher`. With that, it seems you can only `subscribe()` an `org.reactivestreams.Subscriber`.

Comment: Wrap the publisher in a `Mono::from` or a `Flux::from`.

Comment: Can you tell us what problem you have with the `org.reactivestreams.Publisher`?

Comment: Don't use the plain R2DBC but rather use the `DatabaseClient` from Spring R2DBC or use Spring Data R2DBC. The plain R2DBC API and trying to use that will lead you down a path of tears and frustration...

Comment: @K.Nicholas if you add an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a publisher then you need to wrap it in either a `Mono::from` or a `Flux::from` in order to be able to subscribe to it. For a connection you should wrap it in a `Mono::from` and cache it like so.

```
private final Mono<? extends Connection> connection;

public SomeEntityDao() {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
            .option(DRIVER, H2_DRIVER)
            .option(PASSWORD, "")
            .option(URL, "mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")
            .option(USER, "sa")
            .build());
    connection = Mono.from(connectionFactory.create()).cache();
}
```

When you want to use it then you can `Mono::flatMap` the connection and create a statement. Since you did a `Mono::flatMap` on the statement then you can do a `Mono::flatMap` on the result to continue the flow.

```
public Mono<SomeEntity> findById(Long id) {
    return connection.flatMap(con -> Mono.from(con.createStatement("select * from some_entity where id = $1")
                    .bind("$1", id)
                    .execute()))
            .flatMap(result -> Mono.from(result.map(mapper)));
}
```

FYI: My `mapper` is a function.

```
private final BiFunction<Row, RowMetadata, SomeEntity> mapper = (row, rowMetadata) -> {
    SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity();
    someEntity.setId(row.get("id", Long.class));
    someEntity.setName(row.get("name", String.class));
    return someEntity;
};
```

If you are returning more than one Entity, then use `Mono::flatMapMany`

```
public Flux<SomeEntity> findAll() {
    return connection.flatMap(con -> Mono.from(con.createStatement("select * from some_entity")
                    .execute()))
            .flatMapMany(result -> result.map(mapper));
}
```

Ultimately though, if you are using R2DBC, then you should also include the reactive connection pool. Example given at [WebFluxR2dbc](https://github.com/karlnicholas/WebFluxR2dbc).

Comment: Can't I get the current ConnectionFactory from an autowired DatabaseClient?

Comment: The above code is for raw R2DBC. For using the Spring R2DBC libraries refer to their tutorials on that. I assume it will be easier than raw R2DBC. I would not mix the two, if you use [Spring R2DBC DatabaseClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/r2dbc/package-summary.html) refer to their documenation on setting up connection parameters.